# what happen when override spring repository method without implementing

Tags: java, spring, repository-pattern

Here is my `spring` repository interface

```
    interface TupleRepository extends JpaRepository<Tuple, Integer> {

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames="tuples", allEntries=true)
    void delete(Tuple tuple);

}
```

As you see I overrided withoud giving any implementation.
the method is still working.

Which implem is being called.

I tried the debugging and investigation but ended up in the aop class managing the call.

does this method still call the jpaRepository implementation or what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, you did not actually provide an overriding implementation, so there is nothing really to debug on. At the end, the original implementation will be called. The annotations you added on the method should be respected, though.